# Why is jquery hover, to slide functions flashing on drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, drop-down-menu

My sub menu, drop downs, flash when hovering from the 2nd child to the 1st child of a different

. To see this, hover over "projects", then "uhoh", then hover over "project dashboard", then hover over "bam" from there. It flashes and I just don't understand why...........I obviously need it to stop flashing when you hover in special ways so people don't break it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chBVz/8/)

I'm thinking its something along the lines of calling a child ul to show, then that ul's child in another part to show, and the hide and show colliding somehow? Not sure though. I was looking for a way to flow the entire thing but I'm still learning jquery.

[Test Site](http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/fileshare2/index2.php)

Comment: Wow, what's going on with that markup? Using jQuery? Then take full advantage.

Comment: Please provide a cleaner fiddle.. most people don't have 3k wide screens, so your fiddle is rather impossible to work with.

Comment: Fixed. Accidently copied my backup, which is old and really isn't a very good backup at all I suppose.

Comment: I've tried everything and this still isn't going at all. Still flashing show/hide if I dont hover properly through the list.

Comment: I guess I'm just going to not worry about this bug for now, as I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Well when you added the code opacity, thats what makes it "flash", maybe you can remove this portion?

```
.animate({opacity:0.50}).delay (500)
```

Note also that the "Uh oh" and Bam is NOT on the fiddle you sent.

Comment: You could have easily just kept in what the Php _returned_.

Comment: We meant to get the HTML source code (view-source) of page and work with that so we could easily help you out

Comment: Chill out you 2 :) its a great weekend we are all having. just get some beer

Comment: Glad you fixed it Grant :)

Tip:
Don't forget to call jquery stop() before animating to stop any active animations, http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: I actually had stop before every slide or animation, but it made it flash more and break a lot easier for some reason so I took it out. This menu is giving me a headache. Still can't figure this out...

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not working still. Meant I fixed the OP, not the issue I posted for.